# How to send data from an android app to a web server

Tags: android, node.js, rest, laravel-5

I want to create a rating application in android. 
The app will be installed in a mobile device where the user can rate from 0 to 10. Then I want to collect those data to a database and show them in my web application.
I found that I have to create a REST API where the android app will send the data to a web server so I can manipulate them.

How can I send those data from the android app to the webserver?

Which framework should I use to create the REST API? I am between Laravel and Node.js.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Do you want to send data to server from Android App ?

Comment: some good reading here https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777

Comment: Yes. When the user rates in the android app I want to send the rating to the server and then to display the rating to my web application.

Comment: Okay. Have you read any tutorial or do you have request URL to which you will send data?

Comment: I have read these articles:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/connect-android-app-with-laravel-api/
https://www.android-examples.com/volley-post-request-php-mysql/

Comment: Yes. These are good. Go ahead then!

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this you need to follow some steps.

**1. Server-side**

1. Need a database to save the data.
2. Write an API to connect the database with the mobile application.  You can use PHP/JavaScripts to write this REST API.
3. Write an API to communicate with web application

**2. Mobile Application**

1. Create a mobile application
2. Use Volley/Retrofit to send the data to the database via API (1.2)

Comment: `via API (1.2)` what does this mean?